# Tableau - exporting a view as .png is giving me a broken, unopenable png

Tags: tableau-api

```
tabcmd export "innoviCares_I_1404_v01/WeeklyTrendLast26weeks#4" --png -f
Exports\Export1" --username daniel.bak --server http://tableau
```

is my input.

It successfully finds the view, and downloads it as a .png is the correct place. However, when I try to open the .png, it's unopenable and seems corrupted. I've tried multiple times. Any idea what I might have to do?

Comment: What version of Server is this, and does it happen with other workbooks as well?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to repro your issue with version 9.0 so I'm guessing that that's the version you're using. Adding .png to your specified filename fixes the issue. Eg:

```
tabcmd export "innoviCares_I_1404_v01/WeeklyTrendLast26weeks#4" --png -f "Exports\Export1.png" --username daniel.bak --server http://tableau
```

Alternatively, use your original command and then modify the downloaded file so that it has ".png" as a file extension. It should then be possible to open the file as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the #4 at the end of the URL.

I just encountered the same issue.

Comment: Do you know why that would work?  Adding some extra explanation might make it easier for your answer to help others later.